Node.js NativeでExpressのreq.sessionと同じことをしたい
新規登録もしくはログインする際にOAuthを用いてGoogleでログインするサイトを作っています。
import { createServer } from 'http';
createServer((req, res) => {

}).listen(3333);

ログイン画面に入るとNode.js内でstateのランダム文字列を作成し、/login?state=XXXXXのようにstateのパラメーターが作られます。
クライアント側のJavaScriptでStateを受けとってsessionStorage.setItem("state", state)します。
その後Googleのログイン画面に飛んで、Goolgleアカウントを選択し、callbackにリダイレクトした時、sessionStorageに保存されたstateと、リダイレクト時のstateがマッチするかどうかということをしたいです。
しかしクライアント側のJavaScriptでは意味がないので、サーバサイドのNode.js側でしたいのですが、その際、sessionStorageを取得できません。
expressを使えば以下のようにreq.sessionが使用できるのですが、これをネイティブNode.jsでしたいと思っています。
if(req.session.state == state) {}

cookieをうまく使ってSessionStorageのようにするのが普通なのでしょうか？
